# My Perl script starts too slowly, and includes many modules - can I precompile it?

Tags: performance, perl, perl-module

I have a Perl script, that includes a few custom Perl modules.

I have profiled the script using [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf), and I can see that including these Perl modules has a cost that I would like to minimize.

I have installed [`PAR::Packer`](https://metacpan.org/module/PAR%3a%3aPacker) and compiled my script to make it stand alone, but it does not include the custom Perl modules.

Any suggestions?

Edit :

I need to precomplie the script so that i does not include the compilation overhead every time it is evoked.

Comment: How has the profiler revealed that the modules are the problem? Separating the code will have little effect apart from the initial load and compilation.

Comment: `use`-ing a Perl module is not a large cost in itself (unless you are needing very fast start-up of an application). You need to give more details. Maybe just focus on one high cost area, and get help understanding what is going on - provide some details from the profile report, what your understanding is, and what you are considering doing to improve performance in *that* case.

Comment: @Borodin Initial Load and Compilation are the problem because of too many perl modules used. I need a very fast start-up... any suggestions?

Comment: @NeilSlater , Correct I need a very fast start-up, so I thought compiling it will help. But its not helping. I will be sharing my profiler output soon. Any other suggestions till then?

Comment: If you need it to be as fast as that in starting then your design is wrong. You should run it as a daemon that is always running.

Comment: If anything, using `PAR` will slow it down as it has to unzip everything before compiling it. The purpose of `PAR` is just to combine a program with all its dependencies into a single file, not to speed things up.

Comment: @Borodin Do I have any option to sort of precomplie the perl scripts along with its dependencies?

Comment: There is no good option to precompile a Perl script. If you want to improve startup time, load your modules lazily. Some modules are rather heavyweight (e.g. Moose) and have lighter alternatives, which you could use instead. But all we can do here is speculation, because we don't know a thing about your architecture, and the problem domain of your program. Is it a quick command line helper, or a large application that fetches its configuration with a dozen Http requests on startup? Please also give hard metrics, e.g. “*startup currently takes 2s, must be done in 500ms*”.

Comment: I tried perlcc, but it is not stable in perl 5. I think I will be going with Borodin's solution. @Borodin, please give an answer below so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If some of the packages you import are not needed at startup, change `use` calls to `require` and move them to the places in your code where the packages are needed (so you import them when they are needed, not necessarily at startup). Depending on how complex your program is, it could be a lot of work to figure out what calls can be changed without breaking your program or affecting its behavior.

---

Borodin's daemon suggestion is a good one, too. Start a skeleton of your program that loads the necessary packages and waits for something to invoke it (maybe set up a socket connection or a signal handler). Then when it is time for your program to run, `fork` it and call some `&main` subroutine that starts the useful part of your program.

Comment: That seems to be the way to go. I tried perlcc but it is not stable in perl 5.